# Is this a valid covering?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I am trying to find two 5-fold connected covering spaces of $S^1 \vee S^1$ and determine whether they are equivalent or not. I've found two such coverings but I'm not sure if they are actually valid connected coverings, so I was wondering if any could help out.

The first covering I've got is:

[image]

The second one is the same covering as above but with all the $\mathbf{a}$s interchanged with the $\mathbf{b}$s.

I believe the first one (and hence the second one) is a valid covering since:

i) It's connected as it's a wedge sum of circles.
ii) There are 5 disjoint unions that open interval in $S^1 \vee S^1$ will be mapped to.

But again, I am not sure.

Comment: The covering will need to be locally homeomorphic to the base space.  So, all of the vertices must have degree 4.  In a 5-fold covering, there will be 5 vertices.  Try drawing some graphs that are 4-regular and have 5 vertices.  Then see if you can assign labels to the edges in a consistent way.

Comment: @RobertBell So my example wouldn't be a connected covering space as it has only 4 vertices? I'm not sure I understand, since from my POV every open set in the based space has a preimage of locally homeomorphic disjoint sets, indicated by the edges $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}$. Don't exactly understand why there must be 5 vertices...

Comment: It must have $5$ vertices because the cardinality of each fiber of a covering space is the same, in this case $5$. You have a unique vertex downstairs, so their must be exactly $5$ copies lying over it.

Comment: @TabesBridges Okay I understand what you're saying, but I'm still not sure why that would mean my covering isn't 5-sheeted. Because in my example you have 4 vertices but will still have 5 fibres...

Comment: I think you have some terminological confusion going on. The word "fiber" refers to the preimage of a point under some map, so there are infinitely many fibers here. The problem is that what you have sketched cannot be a covering at all since it has fibers of cardinality $5$ over most points, but a total of $6$ vertices lying over the unique vertex downstairs (note that the leftmost and rightmost points are also vertices since two labeled edges meet there).

Comment: Ah I see, I think I understand it better now. Thanks, will have a look at the problem again tomorrow.

Comment: @TabesBridges Surely it's possible to also have a 5-sheeted connected covering with more than 5 vertices. A simple example would be having 5 copies of $S^1 \vee S^1$, no?

Comment: Meaning $5$ disconnected copies of $S^1 \vee S^1$? Each copy has one vertex, so you have $5$ lying over the vertex in the base.

Comment: @TabesBridges No I meant that 5 connected copies, where each copy is connected to the previous copy by a vertex.

Comment: Since $S^1\cap S^1$ is the only vertex, the only thing I can imagine with that description is a bouquet of $10$ circles, which is not a covering. Keep in mind that while the leftmost and rightmost point in your drawing are vertices because each circle in your drawing covers $2$ circles downstairs, the graph structure on $S^1 \vee S^1$ is just a single vertex with two edges, both of which have both endpoints at the unique vertex. And the reason your drawing above is *not* a covering space is because those two vertices on the end are not $4$-valent, so the mapping is not a local homeomorphism.